# Adding ScrollPane to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I am working on a project for my college course. I was just wondering if anyone knew how to add a scrollBar to a JTextArea. At present I have the GUI laid out correctly, the only thing missing is the scroll bar.

This is what the GUI looks like. As you can see on the second TextArea I would like to add the Scrollbar.

[image: GUI]

This is my code where I create the pane. But nothing seems to happen... t2 is the JTextArea I want to add it to.

```
scroll = new JScrollPane(t2);
    scroll.setBounds(10,60,780,500);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Try not to use setBounds and a setLayout(null), instead try using a layout manager.

Comment: It's very hard to know what you're doing wrong based on the little bits of information that you're showing. Perhaps you're setting the size of the JTextArea (something you should never do). Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) so we can see what your code is actually doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Scroll Bar comes when your text goes beyond the bounds of your view area. Don't use [Absolute Positioning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html), for such a small talk at hand, always prefer [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html), do read the first para of the first link, to know the advantage of using a Layout Manager.

What you simply need to do is use this thingy :

```
JTextArea msgArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
msgArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
msgArea.setLineWrap(true);      

JScrollPane msgScroller = new JScrollPane();        
msgScroller.setBorder(
    BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Messages"));
msgScroller.setViewportView(msgArea);

panelObject.add(msgScroller);
```

Here is a small program for your understanding :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JTextAreaScroller
{
    private JTextArea msgArea;
    private JScrollPane msgScroller;
    private JTextArea logArea;
    private JScrollPane logScroller;
    private JButton sendButton;
    private JButton terminateButton;
    private Timer timer;
    private int counter = 0;
    private String[] messages = {
                                    "Hello there\n",
                                    "How you doing ?\n",
                                    "This is a very long text that might won't fit in a single line :-)\n",
                                    "Okay just to occupy more space, it's another line.\n",
                                    "Don't read too much of the messages, instead work on the solution.\n",
                                    "Byee byee :-)\n",
                                    "Cheers\n"
                                };

    private ActionListener timerAction = new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            if (counter < messages.length)
                msgArea.append(messages[counter++]);
            else
                counter = 0;
        }
    };

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat Messenger Dummy");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));

        logArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        logArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        logArea.setLineWrap(true);      

        logScroller = new JScrollPane();        
        logScroller.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Chat Log"));
        logScroller.setViewportView(logArea);

        msgArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        msgArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        msgArea.setLineWrap(true);      

        msgScroller = new JScrollPane();        
        msgScroller.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Messages"));
        msgScroller.setViewportView(msgArea);

        centerPanel.add(logScroller);
        centerPanel.add(msgScroller);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();

        terminateButton = new JButton("Terminate Session");
        terminateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if (timer.isRunning())
                    timer.stop();
                else
                    timer.start();
            }
        });
        sendButton = new JButton("Send");

        bottomPanel.add(terminateButton);
        bottomPanel.add(sendButton);

        contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        timer = new Timer(1000, timerAction);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new JTextAreaScroller().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the outcome of the same :

[image: JTEXTAREA SCROLLER]

Answer (score 2):

The scroll bar by default will only be shown when the content overfills the available viewable area

You can change this via the [`JScrollPane#setVerticalScrollBarPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setVerticalScrollBarPolicy%28int%29) method, passing it `ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS`