# Updating a text area

Tags: java, for-loop, textbox, textarea, logic

I am having trouble updating or "repainting" a text area.I would like the text area to be updated with each cycle of the for loop. I have tried a few things such as calling the `paint();` and `repaint();` functions as well as using `text.append();` and `text.setText();`, however that doesn't seem to work. I also have the for loop set up so that it should append the text every iteration. Here is my code, any help is much appreciated.

Nick.

```
package ********_****_rps;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class AutomatedRoshamboRPS extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    int num = 0;
    int compnum = 0;
    int earnings = 0;
    int wins = 0;
    int losses = 0;
    int ties = 0;
    int roshamboCount = 0;
    int gamesPlayed = 0;
    int i;
    int games = 0;
    String a = "", b;

    void updateStats() {

        String statsToString = stats.getText();
        if (num - compnum == 1 || num - compnum == -2) //won
        {
            wins++;
            gamesPlayed++;

        } else if (num - compnum == 0) //tied
        {
            ties++;
            gamesPlayed++;
        } else { //lost
            losses++;
            gamesPlayed++;
        }
        earnings = +(wins * 2) - (losses * 2) + (roshamboCount * 10) - (roshamboCount * 2);
        stats.setText("STATISTICS:"
                + "\nGames Played:" + gamesPlayed
                + "\nEarnings:" + earnings
                + "\nWins:" + wins
                + "\nTies:" + ties
                + "\nLosses:" + losses
                + "\nRoshambo:" + roshamboCount);

    }
    void game() {
        String userChoice;
        compnum = (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
        switch (num) {
            case 1:
                userChoice = "ROCK";
                break;
            case 2:
                userChoice = "PAPER";
                break;
            case 3:
                userChoice = "SCISSORS";
                break;
            default:
                userChoice = "ROCK";
        }
        if (num - compnum == 1 || num - compnum == -2) {
            text.append("\nYou won!");
            a += userChoice;
        } else if (num - compnum == 0) {
            text.append("\nYou tied!");
        } else {
            text.append("\nYou lost!");
            a = "";
        }

        if (a.equals("ROCKROCKROCK") || a.equals("PAPERPAPERPAPER") || a.equals("SCISSORSSCISSORSSCISSORS")) {
            roshamboCount++;
            a = "";
            if (text.getLineCount() > 10000) {
                text.setText("");
            }
        }
    }

    public AutomatedRoshamboRPS() {
        initComponents();

        text.setText("ROCK PAPER SICSSORS"
                + " \nSelect your throw by clicking on one \nof the options to the left.\n"
                + "---------------------------------------------------");

        rock.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                b = numGames.getText();
                games = Integer.parseInt(b);

                for (int l = 0; l < games; l++) {
                    num = 1;
                    game();
                    updateStats();
                }
            }
        });
        paper.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                b = numGames.getText();
                games = Integer.parseInt(b);

                for (int l = 0; l < games; l++) {
                    num = 2;
                    game();
                    updateStats();
                }
            }
        });
        scissors.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                b = numGames.getText();
                games = Integer.parseInt(b);

                for (int l = 0; l < games; l++) {
                    num = 3;
                    game();
                    updateStats();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        buttonGroup2 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        text = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        stats = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        numGames = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        rock = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        paper = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        scissors = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Automated Roshambo");

        text.setColumns(20);
        text.setEditable(false);
        text.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 13)); // NOI18N
        text.setLineWrap(true);
        text.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(text);

        stats.setColumns(20);
        stats.setEditable(false);
        stats.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(stats);

        jLabel5.setText("Number of games");

        jLabel6.setText("to simulate:");

        rock.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/haughton_nick_rps/Rock.png"))); // NOI18N
        rock.setContentAreaFilled(false);

        paper.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/haughton_nick_rps/Paper.png"))); // NOI18N
        paper.setContentAreaFilled(false);

        scissors.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/haughton_nick_rps/Scissors.png"))); // NOI18N
        scissors.setContentAreaFilled(false);

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(jLabel1)
                .add(80, 80, 80))
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .add(jScrollPane2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(36, 36, 36)
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .add(6, 6, 6)
                                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                                    .add(rock, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .add(scissors, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .add(paper))
                                .add(35, 35, 35)
                                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                    .add(jLabel3)
                                    .add(jLabel2)
                                    .add(jLabel4)))
                            .add(jLabel5)
                            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, false)
                                .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, numGames)
                                .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, jLabel6, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                        .add(18, 18, 18)
                        .add(jScrollPane1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 244, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(32, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(18, 18, 18)
                .add(jLabel1)
                .add(18, 18, 18)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(jScrollPane1)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(jLabel5)
                        .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                        .add(jLabel6)
                        .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                        .add(numGames, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .add(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .add(jLabel2)
                                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                                .add(jLabel3)
                                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                                .add(jLabel4)
                                .add(208, 208, 208))
                            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .add(rock, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                                .add(paper, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                                .add(scissors, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 61, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .add(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))))
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                .add(jScrollPane2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 125, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new AutomatedRoshamboRPS().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField numGames;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton paper;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton rock;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton scissors;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea stats;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea text;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: Can [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), be applied to your case ? Have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13098108/1057230), might this can be of some help.

Comment: Or else you can have a look at [paintImmediately(Rectangle rec)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) or [paintImmediately(int x, int y, int w, int h)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#isPaintingOrigin()) and have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10352884/1057230).

Comment: @GagandeepBali He's looping inside the EDT, blocking any repaint requests!

Comment: @MadProgrammer : But `paintImmediately()` (both variants) method has to  run on the EDT. Though some code fragments in the code provided, seems to be are better suited to SwingWorker, as told in your answer.

Comment: @GagandeepBali The issue I have with your suggestion is not the fact that the call is being made on the EDT, that's fine, it's the fact that the EDT is blocked and isn't able to handle repaint requests.  To be honest, the OP's program isn't doing anything that complex to require `paintImmediately` ;) - IMHO

Answer (score 2):

*"updated with each cycle of the for loop"* - There's a problem.

From what I can tell, your program is simply violating the Event Dispatching Thread by make all it's updates within the content of EDT.  This is preventing the UI from begin updated.

You might like to have a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

**UPDATED**

So, I've looked over your code and modified it (as best as I can) to use a `SwingWoker` instead.  I had playing 2000 games without issue.

```
public class TestRockPaperScissors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestRockPaperScissors();
    }

    public TestRockPaperScissors() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                AutomatedRoshamboRPS frame = new AutomatedRoshamboRPS();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class AutomatedRoshamboRPS extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        int num = 0;
        int compnum = 0;
        int earnings = 0;
        int wins = 0;
        int losses = 0;
        int ties = 0;
        int roshamboCount = 0;
        int gamesPlayed = 0;
        int i;
        int games = 0;
        String a = "", b;

        public void updateStats(int state, int roshamboCount, String result) {

            text.append(result + "\n");

            String statsToString = stats.getText();
            if (state == 0) //won
            {
                wins++;
                gamesPlayed++;

            } else if (state == 1) //tied
            {
                ties++;
                gamesPlayed++;
            } else { //lost
                losses++;
                gamesPlayed++;
            }
            earnings = +(wins * 2) - (losses * 2) + (roshamboCount * 10) - (roshamboCount * 2);
            stats.setText("STATISTICS:"
                    + "\nGames Played:" + gamesPlayed
                    + "\nEarnings:" + earnings
                    + "\nWins:" + wins
                    + "\nTies:" + ties
                    + "\nLosses:" + losses
                    + "\nRoshambo:" + roshamboCount);

        }

        public void setGameState(boolean enabled) {

            numGames.setEnabled(enabled);
            rock.setEnabled(enabled);
            paper.setEnabled(enabled);
            scissors.setEnabled(enabled);

        }

        public AutomatedRoshamboRPS() {
            initComponents();

            text.setText("ROCK PAPER SICSSORS"
                    + " \nSelect your throw by clicking on one \nof the options to the left.\n"
                    + "---------------------------------------------------\n");

            rock.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    b = numGames.getText();
                    games = Integer.parseInt(b);

                    setGameState(false);

                    new GameWorker(AutomatedRoshamboRPS.this, games, 1).execute();

//                    for (int l = 0; l < games; l++) {
//                        num = 1;
//                        game();
//                        updateStats();
//                    }
                }
            });
            paper.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    b = numGames.getText();
                    games = Integer.parseInt(b);

                    setGameState(false);

                    new GameWorker(AutomatedRoshamboRPS.this, games, 2).execute();

//                    for (int l = 0; l < games; l++) {
//                        num = 2;
//                        game();
//                        updateStats();
//                    }
                }
            });
            scissors.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    b = numGames.getText();
                    games = Integer.parseInt(b);

                    setGameState(false);

                    new GameWorker(AutomatedRoshamboRPS.this, games, 3).execute();

//                    for (int l = 0; l < games; l++) {
//                        num = 3;
//                        game();
//                        updateStats();
//                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
        private void initComponents() {

            buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
            buttonGroup2 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            text = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
            jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            stats = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
            jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            numGames = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            rock = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
            paper = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
            scissors = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setResizable(false);

            jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
            jLabel1.setText("Automated Roshambo");

            text.setColumns(20);
            text.setEditable(false);
            text.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 13)); // NOI18N
            text.setLineWrap(true);
            text.setRows(5);
            jScrollPane1.setViewportView(text);

            stats.setColumns(20);
            stats.setEditable(false);
            stats.setRows(5);
            jScrollPane2.setViewportView(stats);

            jLabel5.setText("Number of games");

            jLabel6.setText("to simulate:");

//            rock.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/haughton_nick_rps/Rock.png"))); // NOI18N
            rock.setText("Rock");
            rock.setContentAreaFilled(false);

//            paper.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/haughton_nick_rps/Paper.png"))); // NOI18N
            paper.setText("Paper");
            paper.setContentAreaFilled(false);

//            scissors.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/haughton_nick_rps/Scissors.png"))); // NOI18N
            scissors.setText("Scissors");
            scissors.setContentAreaFilled(false);

            org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                    layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(jLabel1)
                    .add(80, 80, 80))
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .add(jScrollPane2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(36, 36, 36)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(6, 6, 6)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                    .add(rock, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(scissors, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(paper))
                    .add(35, 35, 35)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(jLabel3)
                    .add(jLabel2)
                    .add(jLabel4)))
                    .add(jLabel5)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, false)
                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, numGames)
                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, jLabel6, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .add(18, 18, 18)
                    .add(jScrollPane1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 244, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addContainerGap(32, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                    layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(18, 18, 18)
                    .add(jLabel1)
                    .add(18, 18, 18)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(jScrollPane1)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(jLabel5)
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                    .add(jLabel6)
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                    .add(numGames, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(jLabel2)
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                    .add(jLabel3)
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                    .add(jLabel4)
                    .add(208, 208, 208))
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(rock, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                    .add(paper, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                    .add(scissors, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 61, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))))
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                    .add(jScrollPane2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 125, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap()));

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>
// Variables declaration - do not modify
        private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
        private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
        private javax.swing.JTextField numGames;
        private javax.swing.JToggleButton paper;
        private javax.swing.JToggleButton rock;
        private javax.swing.JToggleButton scissors;
        private javax.swing.JTextArea stats;
        private javax.swing.JTextArea text;
// End of variables declaration
    }

    public class GameWorker extends SwingWorker<Object, GameResults> {

        private int games;
        private int userChoice;
        private int roshamboCount;
        private AutomatedRoshamboRPS parent;

        public GameWorker(AutomatedRoshamboRPS parent, int games, int userChoice) {
            this.games = games;
            this.userChoice = userChoice;
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        protected String toString(int choice) {
            String value = "ROCK";
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    value = "ROCK";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    value = "PAPER";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    value = "SCISSORS";
                    break;
            }

            return value;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            parent.setGameState(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<GameResults> chunks) {

            for (GameResults results : chunks) {
                parent.updateStats(results.state, results.getRoshamboCount(), results.getText());
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

            for (int index = 0; index < games; index++) {
                String text = null;
                int compnum = (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
                int state = 2;
                if (userChoice - compnum == 1 || userChoice - compnum == -2) {
                    text = "You won!  " + toString(userChoice) + " beats " + toString(compnum);
                    state = 0;
                    roshamboCount++;
                } else if (userChoice - compnum == 0) {
                    text = "You tied!  " + toString(userChoice) + " ties with " + toString(compnum);
                    state = 1;
                } else {
                    text = "You lost!  " + toString(userChoice) + " losses to " + toString(compnum);
                    state = 2;
                }

                publish(new GameResults(state, roshamboCount, text));

            }

            return null;

        }
    }

    public class GameResults {

        private String text;
        private int state;
        private int roshamboCount;

        public GameResults(int state, int roshamboCount, String text) {
            this.text = text;
            this.state = state;
            this.roshamboCount = roshamboCount;
        }

        public int getRoshamboCount() {
            return roshamboCount;
        }

        public int getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time but, I don't really understand all of it, and we haven't been taught any of that in the comp sci class I'm in, is there an easier way to put the game() and updateStats() functions on another thread? Thanks again,

Comment: Actually, that is the simplest solution. You cod create your own thread, but then you become responsible for syncing the UI requests back to the Event Dispatching Thread. Take a read through the link I supplied, it will provide more details