# adding ScrollBar to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I want to add a scroll bar into my text area and I know the simple code for adding scroll bar but when I put the code for scroll bar the whole text area disappears!

What is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
private JFrame frame;
private JTextArea textarea;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                SmsForm window = new SmsForm();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public SmsForm() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame("???");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    JPanel groupBoxEncryption = new JPanel();

    final JTextArea textarea=new JTextArea();
    textarea.setBounds(50, 100, 300, 100);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textarea);
    textarea.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

    JScrollPane scrollPanePlain = new JScrollPane(textarea);
    groupBoxEncryption.add(scrollPanePlain);
    scrollPanePlain.setBounds(100, 30, 250, 100);
    scrollPanePlain.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Taking all the advice already provide, but instead of add `textarea` to the frame, add the `scrollPanePlain` instead...

Comment: Stop using `Absolute Positioning` for creating `GUI` instead use a proper `Layout Manager`, that will help you get wonderful results with much less effort. One related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13098108/1057230), for some help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues

- You need to add the `JPanel` `groupBoxEncryption` to the application `JFrame`
- Don't add the `textarea` to the frame - components can only have one parent component
- As already mentioned, you're using `null` layout which doesnt size components - forget about not a layout manager.
- As `JPanel` uses `FlowLayout` by default, you need to override `getPreferredSize` for the panel `groupBoxEncryption`. Better yet use a layout manager such as `GridLayout` that automatically sizes the component

Example

```
JPanel groupBoxEncryption = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).
2. Suggest a preferred size for the text area in the number of rows and columns.
3. Add the text area to a scroll pane before then adding the scroll pane to the GUI.