# JTextArea, setPreferredSize, setSize, setMinimumSize, setMaximumSize - nothing works?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtextarea, preferredsize

I have a JTextArea and it's currently just displayed as a thin line, I can't get it to resize, it won't do anything. It's just too small and won't adjust no matter what properties I change.
Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
private JTextArea outputT;
```

I adjust the properties:

```
    outputT = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    outputT.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    outputT.setEditable(false);
    outputT.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 50));
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: reading (and understanding) a decent tutorial/textbook is **always** order of magnitudes more effective than random method calling ;-) See the tutorial referenced in the swing tag wiki.

Comment: One related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13098108/1057230). Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I have a JTextArea and it's currently just displayed as a thin line,

is required

- put [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) to [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)
- set intial size for [JTextArea(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea%28int,%20int%29) accepted by `LayoutManager` (and `JFrame.pack()`)
- use proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) in the case that you want to set `Min`/`Max`/`PreferredSize`  for (`JTextArea` placed in) `JScrollPane`

Comment: The thing is though, when the GUI frame is big enough the JTextArea resizes to be big enough. If I have the frame on resizeable, I can resize the frame. But when I resize it to be big enough, it's like there's a box beneath the JTextArea stopping it from expanding. But the box is like a set size, and once the frame is big enough the box  moves down, giving the JTextArea space to expand. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: there are four, five possible ways, just to aviod guessing -- For better help sooner, post an SSCCE. short, runnable, compilable ...

Comment: I'd be happy to post code, but it won't be able to compile. I'd be giving the whole source code of the project, I use everything in different bits.
The JTextArea works, but it's just the visibility and size that doesn't. If you have any guesses, I'd be happy to explore them.

Comment: *"If you have any guesses, I'd be happy to explore them."*  I'd guess you need to post an SSCCE (as I suggested over an hour ago)..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xPGZSkve -- test code for download.

Comment: @JohnSmith : I added this line `centerPanel.add(this);` as the third line of `createAndDisplayGUI()` method and commented the fourth last and third last lines of this very method. Now inside `main` method, I am calling this method as `new ProgressBarDemo().createAndDisplayGUI()`, now I can see the `JTextArea`. Yeah, I commented all `setXxXSize()` calls in the constructor as well :-) [Link](http://pastebin.com/WKnDSEW5)